# How to center a text inside a file using STL?

Tags: c++, file, text, stl

I have a text file, length of a string, n for example. And I have to center a text in this file and make length of strings of this file equal to n. Then I just print this strings to console or other file. I can use STL. (getline, ifstream, istream_iterator

And I must use std::vector , std::string and for (auto &w: words).

How to do it? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: did you try to add some white spaces at the begin and at the end of the string to make it length `n`? Then it would be centered.

Comment: To nitpick a little, the STL is the [Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), which despite its name is not the same as the C++ standard library. Parts of the STL was used as inspiration for the C++ standard library, but they are not the same.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you try to solve it using pen and paper first. Draw a long rectangle and divide it into squares, this is supposed to represent the padded result. Then try to calculate where you need to position a few example strings inside the result to get it in the "center". Hint: It involves the length of the result, the length of the string, and a couple of divisions by `2`.

Comment: Further hints: `std::ifstream` and `std::getline`. The vector actually is unnecessary *unless* you maybe want to center strings towards maximum of line length if that one is larger than `n`...

Comment: What's missing from this question - example input and output, and what you've tried so far.